# How to see SQL query in SQL profiler?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

When I issue an update query or another Data Manipulation Language (DML) query that changes the data in the database, using Entity Framework 4, how do I see the query sent to the SQL Server?

Let's say I do something like:

```
someEntityObjectInstance.SomeProperty = newValue;
context.SaveChanges();
```

In this case, there's no ObjectQuery to do a ToTraceString() against, so I can't really see what's going on under the covers. I believe there's some Microsoft SQL Server tool like the profiler or something that will help me see the query.

Also, some Intellitrace in VS 2010 Ultimate does the same thing, I think?

Can you please teach me how to use the SQL 2005 Profiler, if there's any such thing?

**Update**

I am looking at a trace in SQL Server 2005 Profiler now but when I issue a `context.DeleteObject()` call or when I update an object and call `context.SaveChanges()`, I do not see the UPDATE or DELETE queries in the profiler. I only see wierd SELECT queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you answered it, sql server tool called profiler

edit:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx

Comment: I am looking at a trace in SQL Server 2005 Profiler now but when I issue a context.DeleteObject() call or when I update an object and call context.SaveChanges(), I do not see the UPDATE or DELETE queries in the profiler. I only see wierd SELECT queries.

Comment: EF runs update statements with "exec sp_executesql" so you need to trace not only TSQL statements but also SP's to see update statements in the profiler

Comment: @e-mre         I would like to know what would "EF" mean here, I am too looking to see some update, insert and delete statements. I am able to see ´select´statements but not ´update, insert´and ´delete´statements.

Comment: @tough EF is Entity Framework. EF runs some statements not as direct sql commands but rather through sp_executesql. For all these to appear in the profiler you might need to alter the default settings when starting a profiler session.

Comment: @e-mre         looking at the options on EF profiling I could not find anything stated with `mssql-server-profiler`, [Julie Lerman](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490349.aspx) explains different pro-filers used for EF but not `mssql-server-profiler` should I assume its not possible to trace any activity of EF though mssql-server-profiler?

Comment: @tough The profiler I am talking about has nothing to do with EF. It is the profiler application that is installed with sql server client tools. "Sql Server Profiler".

Comment: I'm working with an app that uses nhibernate and I also am completely unable to see any activity even though I have all stored procedure and TSQL events selected.  UPDATE:  I hadn't selected: Stored Procedures, RPC:Starting

Answer (score 16):

There are easier ways, if all you want is see the sql queries as they hit the DB.

Here are two very light-weight Sql profilers that can do the job for various SqlServer flavors, including LocalDb - "*worked on my machine (TM)*"

### ExpressProfiler

By far the easiest to use one (and also the most bare-bones-show-me-the-SQL-statements-kthxbye) is [ExpressProfiler on CodePlex](https://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/).

Download tiny ZIP, *wonder if you really got the whole file* (you did), run EXE inside, BAM!

[image]

And the whole program is a single 126 KB EXE ! Now that's lightweight!

### AnjLab Sql Profiler

The other one is the one from [DataWizard](http://www.datawizard.com/), which used to be free (apparently prices now start at $5).

Somebody managed to save a [snapshot on GitHub](https://github.com/ren85/free-sql-server-profiler) (including xcopy-installable binaries) when it was open-source.

The executable presents itself as "AnjLab Sql Profiler" and allows some filtering of the displayed events - but this strength is also its weakness, as there are sooo many event types that can be enabled/disabled. If everything is selected, the output is overwhelmingly verbose.

A saner output can be obtain by only selecting specific events.

[image]

Here are the events I have selected in order to get the above output:

[image]

Comment: mate, ur my hero, expressprofiler is the BOMB! super light weight and works like a charm, no hastle, nothing

Comment: @WtFudgE Glad you like it :)

Comment: ExpressProfiler now seems to be source-only and has been moved to https://github.com/OleksiiKovalov/expressprofiler It compiled without issue and seems to work, though I still havent found update query syntax in its displays.