# How can I identify which functions and sql procedures are causing high cpu usage on the host server

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I have a c#/asp.net web application (non mvc) that has some pages which access a sql database many times, using stored procedures and views.
The application now has 5-10 users, and the hosts have informed me that it's causing 95%+ cpu usage on the server.

My question, how can I identify which functions/procedures/threads are causing the high cpu use so I can cache or optimise them?
Note the hosts do not give me access to ANY server logs, stats, or serversystem database tables, only my application's database, which causes a major headache!

Comment: Tag dbms used, since this is a product specific question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use SqlProfiler to trace the performance and behavior of any SQL procedure, function and etc.

You can check this: [SqlProfiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118521/how-to-see-sql-query-in-sql-profiler) as it's a very helpful tool and it's really help me a lot in enhancing sql stored procedures performance.

You will run your application but before that go to your sql profiler and configure it to listen only on the needed events, like 'procedure completed' and select your filtering criteria like your database or execution user then when you make any action in your app related to database, profiler will track it and analyze it.

You can check the step by step usage of it [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21371/SQL-Server-Profiler-Step-by-Step).

About your C# functions that not related to data access you can measure it's performance using stopwatch class to calculate it's execution time:

```
var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
// the code that you want to measure comes here
watch.Stop();
var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

Or you can [Analyze Performance While Debugging in Visual Studio 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn973013.aspx)

Comment: Thanks i'll try that

Answer (score 1):

You will need to profile .NET code and SQL separately. I'll tackle the SQL part.

Here's a modified version of [Pinal Dave's query](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/05/14/sql-server-find-most-expensive-queries-using-dmv/) which finds recent expensive queries using `sys.dm_exec_query_stats`. I've tweaked it to include the hot path to show you the bottleneck. The query plan will help you further break it down.

```
SELECT TOP 50
  st.text AS [SQL Definition]
, SUBSTRING(
    st.text,
    qs.statement_start_offset / 2 + 1,
    ( CASE
        WHEN qs.statement_end_offset = -1 
        THEN LEN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), st.text)) * 2 
        ELSE qs.statement_end_offset
      END - qs.statement_start_offset ) / 2
  ) AS [Hot Path]
, qs.execution_count AS [Execution Count]
, qs.total_worker_time / 1000000 AS [Total CPU (s)]
, (qs.total_worker_time / $1000000) / qs.execution_count AS [Average CPU (s)]
, qs.total_elapsed_time / 1000000 AS [Total Time (s)]
, qs.total_logical_reads / qs.execution_count AS [Average Logical Reads]
, qs.total_logical_writes / qs.execution_count AS [Average Logical Writes]
, qs.total_physical_reads / qs.execution_count AS [Average Physical Reads]
, ISNULL(qp.query_plan, '') AS [Query Plan]
  FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs WITH (NOLOCK)
 CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) AS st
 CROSS apply sys.dm_exec_query_plan (qs.plan_handle) AS qp
 ORDER BY [Total CPU (s)] DESC
```

This is obviously just a starting point, but if your problem is due to an inefficient query or missing index, it'll point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy the applicaton locally and diagnose away.

If your application can choke a server, it will most likely kill your machine too.

Comment: On a side note: the server gets choked by a single application with 10 users ? are they hosting you on a 486 laptop, or is the application handling that much data ?

Comment: It only uses < 1% on my local machine, even if I use the app a lot. They have upto date server hardware, not sure how it's configured though, shared hosting.

Comment: The server simply sucks then, either wait for the upgrade or look for a new hosting...

Answer (score 0):

In case you call the store procedure from your application:

Add option for verbose trace logs on your application, (you will enable it only when you want to check scenarios as you described).
Trace the time, cpu ... for each method that you suspect that cause the problem
(if you can't get the logs file, trace the time to your database).
From the function on your method you can find the store procedure

Comment: it's a good practice to add logs for all such cases on production environments, because it's your only way to know what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Sql Profiler, as mentioned previously, is your best bet. However, I think you would need the developer edition / tools for SQL server before you can use it.

More often than not, Sql Server will take a long time to load and / or use high CPU if it keeps on doing table scan(s).

Adding indexes to the table will help. 
You should also check in case you have accidentally missed out on creating primary key(s) for the tables.

In case, you think some fields might be unique - then specify unique constraints appropriately. For example, email address field in a Customer table might be unique.

Additionally, try avoiding "like" on nvarchar fields. If you you xml fields, see if you can store the most important field separately in a column. For example, in of the Sql Servers that I worked on, one of the unique "id" fields was within a XML column - making Sql queries slow.